# Android studio cannot find declaration to go to in xml layout files

Tags: xml, android-studio

I know it has been asked several times, but I tried every suggested solution and the problem still persists.
In code files, I can go to declaration of variables by pressing  +  as usual, it even jumps to xml files.  But in XML layout files, I have no intellisense autocompletion, nor can I jump to declaration to other resources.

I tried cleaning and rebuilding the project, deleting .idea and build directories, deleting recursively all .iml files, the "Invalidate Caches and Restart" options in the File menu, creating a new project from scratch (it has just the same problem),...

```
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        />
```

It even says "Unknown attribute android:text"

Answer (score 0):

I came out with this solution, posting it here in case it can help anyone

I deleted the caches subdirectory at C:\Users\user.AndroidStudio3.5\system